# Display attachments by the ID of the post being edited in the wp.media frame (frontend)

Tags: uploads, media, media-library, media-modal, media-settings

There is a button in the frontend on the post page to upload images. How do I display attachments that are attached to this post in the wp.media frame? How to intercept wp.media's AJAX request for attachments to filter attachments by post ID?

**Here's what I have:**

**function.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','bla_bla');
function bla_bla(){
    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('bla_bla_bla','/script.js','',true);
}
```

**script.js**

```
var wpMedia;
var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id;     // keeping the old post id

$('button.upload').on('click',function(event){              // file upload button in post
    var btn = $(event.target);
    var postID = btn.attr('post-id'),                           // например получим ID записи из атрибута "post-id" кнопки

    if (wpMedia){                                               // if the media frame already exists, it will reopen
        wpMedia.uploader.uploader.param('post_id',postID);          // sets the post ID to which the attachment file will be attached
        wpMedia.open();                                             // open wp.media
        return;
    }else{
        wp.media.model.settings.post.id = postID;                   // sets the id of the wp.media post so that the loader gets the id it needs on initialization
    }

    var insertImage = wp.media.controller.Library.extend({      // frame options wp.media
        defaults: _.defaults({
            id: 'insert-image',                                     // 
            title: titleForWpMediaFrame,                            // media uploader header
            displaySettings: true,                                  // file display settings
            //filterable: 'all',                                    // show all filters
            multiple: false,                                        // single file selection
            type: ['video','audio','image','application/pdf'],      // Supported file formats (DOES NOT WORK)
        },wp.media.controller.Library.prototype.defaults)
    });
    wpMedia = wp.media.frames.wpMedia = wp.media({              // initialize the loader window (create a new media frame)
        button: {text: 'Button text',},                             // button name
        state: 'insert-image',
        states: [new insertImage()],
    });

    wpMedia.open();                                             // open wp.media

    wpMedia.on('select',function(){                             // handler that runs after file selection
        var attachment = wpMedia.state().get('selection').first().toJSON(); // uploaded image dataset
        console.log(attachment);                                    // prints the data of the selected file to the console
        wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;         // recovering the main post ID
    });
});
```

There is no script here that I tried to solve the problem because it never worked (I think this is pretty simple, but I could not find instructions on how to do it ...